# sum(isnull(DB.budget_amount,0)) OVER(Partition by DB.ACCOUNT)as YearTotalBudget (Adding this line with a group by causes issue )

Tags: sql-server, partitioning

```
SELECT     
    b.GlDtlTID, b.CORP, b.CORPNAME, hr.Function_Name, hr.Busunit_Name, 
    b.CostCenter, hr.Department_Code, hr.Department_Name, b.CostCenterName, 
    b.CostCenter + ' - ' + b.CostCenterName AS CostCenter_Name, 
    b.ACCOUNT, b.ACCTNAME, b.FISCAL_YEAR_PERIOD, b.TxnType, b.ACTUAL_AMT, 
    ISNULL(b.BUDGET_AMT, 0) AS BUDGET_AMT, ISNULL(b.FORECAST_AMT, 0) AS FORECAST_AMT,  
    ISNULL(b.BUDGET_AMT, 0) - b.ACTUAL_AMT AS VARIANCE_AMT, 
    b.BatchPosted, b.DESCRIPTION, b.AFE, b.AFENAME, b.VENDOR, b.VENDORNAME, b.INVOICEREF,
    SUM(ISNULL(DB.budget_amount, 0)) OVER (PARTITION BY DB.ACCOUNT) AS YearTotalBudget --Adding this line
FROM        
    BI_dept_actualbudget AS b 
LEFT OUTER JOIN   
    BI_BusUnit_HR AS hr ON b.CostCenter = hr.Hier_Code
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    BI_Dept_Budget DB ON DB.CORP = b.CORP 
                      AND DB.CORPNAME = B.CORPNAME 
                      AND DB.dept = b.CostCenter 
                      AND DB.ACCOUNT= B.ACCOUNT -- And this line 
WHERE    
    b.account NOT IN (
        '1022-010','1022-040','2500-022','2500-023','2500-024','2500-025','2500-026','2500-030',
        '2500-035','2500-040','2500-045','2500-050','2500-055','2500-060','2500-065','2500-070','2500-075',
        '6000-010','6000-011','6000-012','6000-013','6000-015','6000-016','6000-017','6000-018','6000-019',
        '6000-110','6000-111','6000-112','6000-113','6000-115','6000-116','6000-117','6000-118','6000-119',
        '6100-010','6100-015',
        '6110-010','6110-015','6110-020','6110-025','6110-035','6110-040','6110-045','6110-050','6110-055',
        '6110-065','6110-075','6110-080','6110-085','6115-010','6115-015',
        '6120-015','6120-020','6120-025','6320-010',
        '6905-000','6905-010','6905-020','6905-030','6110-110','6110-115','6110-120','6110-135','6110-140')
  AND DB.dept = 'D1100' 
GROUP BY 
    b.GlDtlTID, b.CORP, b.CORPNAME, hr.Function_Name, hr.Busunit_Name, 
    b.CostCenter, hr.Department_Code, hr.Department_Name, b.CostCenterName, 
    b.CostCenter + ' - ' + b.CostCenterName, b.ACCOUNT, b.ACCTNAME, 
    b.FISCAL_YEAR_PERIOD, b.TxnType, b.ACTUAL_AMT, 
    ISNULL(b.BUDGET_AMT, 0), ISNULL(b.FORECAST_AMT, 0), 
    ISNULL(b.BUDGET_AMT, 0) - b.ACTUAL_AMT, 
    b.BatchPosted, b.DESCRIPTION, b.AFE, b.AFENAME, 
    b.VENDOR, b.VENDORNAME, b.INVOICEREF
```

I am getting this error:

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
>   Column 'BI_Dept_Budget.ACCOUNT' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Please help.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Group by and Partition are contradictory by nature. When you use group by, you group your records based on columns. When you use partition, your intention is not to loose any records and still use some aggregation against each record.

From your query, I feel that if you use SELECT DISTINCT ... and just remove your froup by clause, that should server your purpose.

```
`SELECT  DISTINCT
b.GlDtlTID, b.CORP, b.CORPNAME, hr.Function_Name, hr.Busunit_Name, 
b.CostCenter, hr.Department_Code, hr.Department_Name, b.CostCenterName, 
b.CostCenter + ' - ' + b.CostCenterName AS CostCenter_Name, 
b.ACCOUNT, b.ACCTNAME, b.FISCAL_YEAR_PERIOD, b.TxnType, b.ACTUAL_AMT, 
ISNULL(b.BUDGET_AMT, 0) AS BUDGET_AMT, ISNULL(b.FORECAST_AMT, 0) AS FORECAST_AMT,  
ISNULL(b.BUDGET_AMT, 0) - b.ACTUAL_AMT AS VARIANCE_AMT, 
b.BatchPosted, b.DESCRIPTION, b.AFE, b.AFENAME, b.VENDOR, b.VENDORNAME, b.INVOICEREF,
SUM(ISNULL(DB.budget_amount, 0)) OVER (PARTITION BY DB.ACCOUNT) AS YearTotalBudget -- 
Adding this line
FROM        
BI_dept_actualbudget AS b 
LEFT OUTER JOIN   
BI_BusUnit_HR AS hr ON b.CostCenter = hr.Hier_Code
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
BI_Dept_Budget DB ON DB.CORP = b.CORP 
                  AND DB.CORPNAME = B.CORPNAME 
                  AND DB.dept = b.CostCenter 
                  AND DB.ACCOUNT= B.ACCOUNT -- And this line 
WHERE    
b.account NOT IN (
    '1022-010','1022-040','2500-022','2500-023','2500-024','2500-025','2500- 
026','2500-030',
    '2500-035','2500-040','2500-045','2500-050','2500-055','2500-060','2500- 
065','2500-070','2500-075',
    '6000-010','6000-011','6000-012','6000-013','6000-015','6000-016','6000- 
017','6000-018','6000-019',
    '6000-110','6000-111','6000-112','6000-113','6000-115','6000-116','6000-117','6000-118','6000-119',
    '6100-010','6100-015',
    '6110-010','6110-015','6110-020','6110-025','6110-035','6110-040','6110-045','6110-050','6110-055',
    '6110-065','6110-075','6110-080','6110-085','6115-010','6115-015',
    '6120-015','6120-020','6120-025','6320-010',
    '6905-000','6905-010','6905-020','6905-030','6110-110','6110-115','6110-120','6110-135','6110-140')
  AND DB.dept = 'D1100'`
```

Comment: Thanks Ayush.  Really Appreciated.